# Generate meta description in Astro.build

Tags: javascript, astrojs

I want to generate a description of the current page content for my meta tags in Astro.build. I've looked into the Astro API Reference, but couldn't find the thing I'm looking for. I've come up with a simple createDescription function:

```
export function createDescription(content: string) {
    const paragraphs = content.split('\n\n');
    return paragraphs[0];
}
```

For every page in my Astro project I call the function and want to pass the current page content. So I'm looking for some kind of function that gets all the page data in Astro.

An example of the usage would be:

```
---
import Layout from "../layouts/app.astro"
import { createDescription } from "./getContents.ts";
const desc = createDescription(getCurrentPageContents())
---
<Layout
    description=desc
>
    // All the page content
</Layout>
```

Comment: Hi @Keygun2k1, The question is, which mode (SSG or SSR) you use. If you use SSG for instance, you need to return props inside the `getStaticPaths` method. Inside that method, you can perform the description creation. Read more about it: https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/api-reference/#getstaticpaths

Comment: If you use the markdown pages, you will have the following props passed to the astro layout: https://docs.astro.build/en/core-concepts/layouts/#markdown-layout-props

Comment: Hi @LeifMarcus this was the solution thanks! Initially I didn't want to do it this way, but just doing it using javascript. That isn't ideal, because then I'll have to add the meta tags through javascript after the page load on the client side. Now when using `getStaticPaths` and providing the description as a property I can achieve the same result.